# How to access parse.com REST API after migrating to local server?

Tags: python, api, rest, parse-platform

I have been using parse as my project server and now that I have migrated the data to local server, successfully made dashboard work; but I cannot find a way to access `api.parse.com/1/` API.

I used to use python to make REST requests and it is basically establishes socket connection with `api.parse.com` at port `443`. Now I am trying to connect to `localhost` at port `1337` which is where the parse-server instance is running. However, I have not been able to access the API same as before.

One thing to note is that I can successfully `curl` to get basic JSON response from requests like

```
curl -X GET -H ... http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/_User
```

The question is which connection now replaces `api.parse.com` for locally held parse-server instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I found out the answer:

You make socket connection with `address` and `port` where the `parse-server` is running, and then instead of doing

```
conn.request("GET", "/1/login?%s"%...)
```

You do:

```
conn.request("GET", "/parse/login?%s"%...)
```

Hope this helps.